# How to get multiple returns from multiple functions and send response in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating application using dns module of node js I want to print A,Mx,ns and soa records at once I'm using this method but in the end I get undefined.

```
const dns =require('dns');
dns.resolveMx('google.com',async (err,address)=>{
console.log(mx);
})

dns.resolve6('google.com',(err,address)=>{
console.log("V6: "+address);
 })


 dns.resolve4('goole.com',(err,address)=>{
 console.log("V4: "+address);
 })

  dns.resolveNs('google.com',(err,address)=>{
   console.log("NS: "+address);
    })

   dns.resolveSoa('google.com',async (err,address)=>{
  console.log(address);
 })

 dns.resolveTxt('google.com',(err,address)=>{
  console.log("TXT: "+address);
 })

  console.log(I want everything here so I can res.send it)
```

Edit:
I tried this

```
const calls = [
dns.resolveMx('google.com',(err,address)=>{return address}),
dns.resolve6('google.com',(err,address)=>{return address})
]

console.log(calls);
```

but returns

```
[
QueryReqWrap {
bindingName: 'queryMx',
callback: [Function],
hostname: 'google.com',
oncomplete: [Function: onresolve],
ttl: false,
channel: ChannelWrap {}
},
QueryReqWrap {
bindingName: 'queryAaaa',
callback: [Function],
hostname: 'google.com',
oncomplete: [Function: onresolve],
ttl: false,
  channel: ChannelWrap {}
}
]
```

Instead of MX records and AAAA record.

Answer (score 0):

Because its async calls. You could use Promise to group it up and then print it when all the calls are done.

example with two of the functions.

```
const dns =require('dns');

const getMx = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.resolveMx('google.com',async (err,address)=>{
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(address)
        })
    });
};

const get6 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.resolve6('google.com',(err,address)=>{
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(address);
        })
    });
}

const calls = [
    getMx(),
    get6(),
];

Promise.all(calls).then((results) => {
    console.log(results[0]);
    console.log(results[1]);
})
```

NB! I did not see from the documentation if the functions has Promise support, maybe you're able to do do

```
..
const calls = [
  dns.resolveMx('google.com'),
  dns.resolve6('google.com'),
]
..
```

Comment: What I did in my solution was to wrap the async function with a callback into a Promise, then run all the promises and handle the result. Seems like you just wrote the functions into an array and printed the list.